# Angular filtering array with radio buttons

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, filter, pipe

I have a **JSON** list which containing few categorized audio files and their URLs.

```
export const musicList = [
  {
    'id': 0,
    'catName': 'upload',
    'audios': [
      {
        'id': 0,
        'name': 'crowd-cheering.mp3',
        'path': 'a.com/music.mp3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 1,
    'catName': 'rock',
    'audios': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Consectetur',
        'path': 'a.com/music.mp3'
      },
      {
        'id': 2,
        'name': 'Vivamus',
        'path': 'a.com/music.mp3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    'id': 2,
    'catName': 'folk',
    'audios': [
      {
        'id': 1,
        'name': 'Suspendisse',
        'path': 'a.com/music.mp3'
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I list these musics with `*ngFor` like :

```
<div *ngFor="let music of musicList">
  <div *ngFor="let audio of music.audios"> 
    {{audio.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I am listing their categories with radio buttons also :

```
<div *ngFor="let category of musicList">
  <input type="radio" name="genre"> {{category.catName}}
</div>
```

I just want to add a filter option. I meant when user select one radio button, list should show audio files related with selected category.

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Typescript : 2.7.2
```

Comment: Looks more like Angular than AngularJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change and call a function passing the filter you want

Comment: Problem is i do not know how to pass filter with ng-change, also ng-change is not working anymore.

Comment: try this (change)='filterCategory(category.catName)'

Comment: Where should i add this? I tried to add this on input radio buttons but : "ERROR TypeError: _co.filterCategory is not a function"